# ResGen генерируемые файлы (локализация)

Tags: c#, resources

Установил русскую Visual Studio. теперь ресурсы генерируются с русскими комментариями, но у нас на проекте все на английском. Как можно перенастроить мой инструментарий (например ResGen) для того, чтобы генерация `Designer.cs` стала с английскими комментариями?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например сменить язык **Visual Studio** выбрать `Сервис->Параметры->Среда->Выбор языка->Получить дополнительные языки`, после этого выбрать английский язык и перезапустить студию, незнаю насколько это вам поможет, но язык самой студии тоже сменится. Валидно для **2013** и **2015** студий, для более ранних сказать не могу, давно не использовал

Comment: спасибо, помогло